# mathjax-script is giving error specification mandates value for attribute async

Tags: mathjax, mathml, epub.js, sigils

Why math Jax script is not working in sigil software for EPUB file.

Working fine everywhere except sigil

Error in Sigil : Specification values for attribute async

I am trying to put mathjax script in Sigil but any script is not working in Sigil